# why promise has a weird precedence for errors in js?

Tags: javascript, promise, throw

I have the code below and I expect to first have `hi` in my console then the `error` and at the end `why`, but the result is: `hi`, then `why` and the last one is `error`, so I'm wondering, why is this happening?

code:

```
const test = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
 console.log("hi");
 throw new Error("error");
})

test.finally(() => {
  console.log("why")
})
```

Comment: Nothing special about promises here. `try { console.log("Hi"); throw new Error("error"); } finally { console.log("why"); }` has the same output (apart from saying "uncaught exception" instead of "unhandled rejection").

Comment: Where/when would you have expected to see the error and why?

Comment: the `new Promise` itself is a sync operation, first it reads the `hi` then the `error` so after the error it goes for `why`, and I have mentioned what I expected in my question. @bergi

Comment: Oh I overread that. But why do you expect to see the error in the console immediately when it's thrown?

Comment: because based on its precedence, it has to?@Bergi

Comment: Well the `throw` is executed before that `.finally()`, sure, but that has not mean it has to be logged first. It's only printed when it has been caught by the runtime, and that happens after the `finally` executes.

Comment: why then?@Bergi

Comment: Because thrown errors are **NEVER** meant to be printed on the console. They are meant to be **caught**. But you never catch the thrown error. But how would javascript know that you're not catching without excecuting all the code that can be executed? Apart from inventing a time machine it can't. So it waits for you to catch it (which you never do). And when finally there is nothing left to do it notices that you never catch the error and helpfully prints a message to you telling you that you did not catch the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I expect to first have `hi` in my console then the error and at the end `why`

That's what you'd get **if** you were handling the rejection of the promise, like this:

```js
const test = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    console.log("hi");
    throw new Error("error");
});

test
.catch((error) => console.error(error))
.finally(() => {
    console.log("why")
});
```

...but your code isn't handling rejection, so the rejection isn't reported until the environment's unhandled rejection code kicks in, which isn't until after all the code explicitly handling the promise has been executed.

As you've said in a comment, `new Promise` and the execution of the function you pass it are all synchronous, but the error thrown in that function isn't unhandled, it's handled by the `Promise` constructor and converted to a promise rejection (which, *later*, is unhandled).

So the sequence is:

1. Create a promise
2. Output `hi`
3. Reject the promise with the error
4. Attach a `finally` handler to it
5. Run any appropriate handlers attached to the promise (since it's settled), in this case your `finally` handler

   1. Output `why`
   2. Reject the promise created by `finally`
6. Determine that the rejection is unhandled and report it